# Not getting AJAX response

Tags: jquery, ajax

I've had a look at a couple of examples but I just haven't been able to get my head around this.

I have the following form:

```
<div id="a_dialog" title="My dialog" style="display:none"> 
<form action="/path/myPath" id="trigger" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">

<br>

<input type="file" name="uploadedFile" >
<input type="submit" value="Upload">

</form>
</div>

$("#trigger").submit(function(){

$.ajax({
    url: '/path/myPath',
    data: new FormData(this),
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(data){
        alert(data);
    }
});

});
```

When I upload a file I am redirected and get the following response

```
{"status": {"message": "link_to_the_file", "code": 0}}
```

How do I:

1. Prevent the redirection
2. Get the response in the alert?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a button of type `submit` within a form, default action is a postback. Prevent that!

```
$("#trigger").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
```